# Maximize size of Silverlight content after it has loaded

Tags: c#, silverlight, window, maximize

I have an HTML page containing Silverlight content. The window initially opens minimized. 
If I maximized the window while the Silverlight content is being loaded, the Silverlight Application opens with the full screen size. But If I waited till the Silverlight application has loaded then I tried to maximize the browser window, the Silverlight size is not refreshed and stays small.

How can I refresh the size of the Silverlight application after maximizing the browser window ?

Comment: Is the issue that the HTML container for Silverlight not resizing or the contente _within_ the Silverlight application not resizing? (If the former, might need to post/fix your HTML code. If the latter, check out the [`SizedChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.sizechanged%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) event on your top-most root XAML control)

Comment: It's the Siverlight content not resizing. Yes, I added an event to handle App.Current.Host.Content.Resized. It worked well, check my answer  below. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used the answer [here](https://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/resize-silverlight-xaml-browser-window-155099.aspx) :

> public Page()
>
> { InitializeComponent();
>
> App.Current.Host.Content.Resized +=newEventHandler(Content_Resized); }
>
> void Content_Resized(object sender, EventArgs e) {
>
> this.Width =App.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth; this.Height
>   =App.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight;
>
> }

Comment: You should not have to do this.

Comment: Well, without these lines, after maximizing the window the silverlight application takes the size of the small window. The size is not refreshed. Can you tell me why it should be working fine ?